# Using PowerShell to grant access to a folder for an "IIS AppPool"

Tags: powershell, iis, application-pool

I Writing a script to automate the deployment of my platform but i cant figure out how to set an app pool to have the permissions with the code i have below it just inserts the text below with the app pool name. I assume this is because this is a frendily name and when you click check names normally it will fetch the correct user but i cant figure out hot to do this in powershell.

```
function Set_iis_perms {
    param (
        [parameter(position=0)]
        $AppPoolName,
        [parameter(position=1)]
        $FileName
    )
    $acl = Get-Acl $FileName
    $acl.AddAccessRule((New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule(("iis apppool\$Apppool_Name"),"Modify","Allow")))
    $acl | Set-Acl $FileName
}
```

Even if someone can point me in the right direction i would be most thankful.

Kind Regards
Dom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting ACL via Get/Set-ACL and icacls is a really common thing and covered in many resources. Example(s):

> [Setting ACL on folder or file using PowerShell](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Setting-ACL-on-folder-or-2c9a60fc)
>
> This script will set folder permission on a folder (c:\1 and C:2) and
>   its sub folder. If the folder does not exist, it will create the
>   folder, set as shared and add the groups to the folder. Group_Name
>   has to be replaced with Actual Group.
>
> [Application Pool Identities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities)
>
> [Setting permissions for ASP.NET application on IIS with
>   PowerShell](https://dejanstojanovic.net/powershell/2018/january/setting-permissions-for-aspnet-application-on-iis-with-powershell)

As per this StackOverflow Q&A

> [How can I add ACL permissions for IIS APPPOOL* accounts via
>   Powershell?](https://serverfault.com/questions/303097/how-can-i-add-acl-permissions-for-iis-apppool-accounts-via-powershell)

```
Set-Acl $directory $acl $user = New-Object
System.Security.Principal.NTAccount("$domain\\$username")
```

> UPDATE: Seems that it won't accept the "IIS APPPOOL\AppPoolName" as an
>   NTAccount identifier. Now, there are two ways to accomplish what you
>   are trying to do:
>
> Create a new SID object with the AppPoolIdentities SID and translate
>   it into an NTAccount, like this:
>   http://iformattable.blogspot.com/2007/12/convert-sid-to-ntaccount-with.html,
>   and you should be able to treat it like any other NTAccount object. If
>   you still want to be able to pass domain/usernames for real accounts,
>   built in some simple logic that defaults to the AppPool SID if
>   username is "AweSomeAppPool" and domain is empty, just as an example.
>
> Use PowerShell to invoke icacls.exe, and use it to grant/revoke
>   whatever permissions you want, like this (first normal icacls form
>   command prompt, then powershell, notice the difference):

```
icacls.exe test.txt /grant "IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool":(OI)(CI)M
cmd /c icacls test.txt /grant "IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool:(OI)(CI)M"
```

Comment: Thank you, my problem was windows and capitalisation i really appreciated that thought. I put me on the right track.